# Build OpenCV 4.2 to use CUDA backend - CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY set to NOTFOUND (Windows 10)

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to build OpenCV 4.2 with CMake in order to use the following function in my Python code to use the GPU instead of the CPU for inference (with CUDA 10.2):

```
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
```

However, I got the following error:

```
 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20191202::Net::Impl::setUpNet DNN module was not built with CUDA backend; switching to CPU
```

After a quick search, it seems that I need to build openCV from source using CMake (3.17.0) instead of using a pip installation.

I did the following on CMake (with OpenCV version 4.2 and also with version 3.4.2.17 that was advised to me):

- Select the source and the build folders
- Enter a value for OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH with the path of the opencv-contrib repository + /modules
- Press configure
- Check WITH_CUDA entry
- Press configure
- Press generate

I get the following error that appears immediately:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "opencv_cudev" in directory C:/Users/samelson/opencv-3.4.2/modules/cudev
    linked by target "opencv_test_cudev" in directory C:/Users/samelson/opencv-3.4.2/modules/cudev/test
    linked by target ...
```

With tons of similar lines started with "linked by target"

I get the same error with the two versions of OpenCV.

Any hint to solve this problem?

Comment: I managed to make it work by following this [nice tutorial](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-2-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-2-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/)